# powershell ilike operator not returning true

Tags: powershell, wildcard, string-matching

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $string = "hello world"
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $string -ilike "hello"
False
```

the above is outputing false, and not true. not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: you're missing a wildcard char to make it match, `-like "hello*"` also the `i` before `like` is not needed.

Comment: In short: The wildcard-based `-like` operator (and its variants) performs matching against the _whole_ input string (unlike the regex-based `-match` operator).
Therefore, `*` is needed for _substring_ matching, for any part not literally specified; e.g.`'foo bar' -like 'foo*'`.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: in this case `$string.Contains("hello")` is much better